# Network Problems

Tags: internet, home-networking

I have a problem with my home network where the internet is suddenly down for a few minutes and then works fine again. I would like to determine where the problem is (switch, router, access point). We have a pretty standard setup, with a router and a gigabit ethernet switch in the basement. And 3 Access Points (Unifi AP Pro), one on every floor. The coverage is fine. However we do have this issue where the Wifi is done maybe once or twice a day.

To determine where the problem is, I would like to somehow monitor the network, at each point, that is straight from the router, from the switch, and from each AP.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: what have you tried? How longs are the outages? Do they affect all devices? Do you have any device which you can connect to the internet through a cable? is that affected? ...

Answer (score 1):

Start a continuous Ping towards the gateway of your closest AP. Then toward the next one and so forth until you get to the main router, then toward ISP gateway.

Example:

`ping 192.168.1.0 -t` (1st AP)

`ping 192.168.2.0 -t` (next AP)

`ping 192.168.3.0 -t` (last AP)

`ping 192.168.10.0 -t` (router)

`ping 1.2.3.0 -t`(ISP gateway)

`ping 8.8.8.8 -t`(Google DNS).

Have them started according to your network IPs.

When the connection fails, you will be able to pinpoint exactly where the problem is.

You can also output those as into files, so you can study them any time.
Just append

`> X:\Path\FileName.Log`

to the command and the output will be in a file instead of being displayed.

Answer (score -2):

Start with pinging the first device you connect to, which is probably the AP. If that is up, ping the next device which would be the switch. Keeping working your way out of the network by pinging each device until you find the one that fails.